# how would i use grep to find words in a file that start and end with specified letter?

Tags: grep

I want to match all the words in a file that start with "s" and end with "n" so i tried this before

```
grep "\bs.*n\b"
```

but it contain  part of the line and i need just words

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like this, assuming words can be from 2 characters to ∞:

```
grep -oE '\bs[[:alpha:]]*n\b' file
```

- `-o` display only matching part
- `-E` is to use `ERE` regex flavor

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |
| `s` | s |
| `[[:alpha:]]*` | any character of: letters (zero or more times) |
| `n` | n |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |

---

Example:

```
$ cat file
sn
aaaaa soon sss saaaaan
bbb siiiiiiiiin xxx sXXXXXXn
```

```
$ grep -oE '\bs[[:alpha:]]*n\b' file
```

```
sn
soon
saaaaan
siiiiiiiiin
sXXXXXXn
```